# asp.net MVC Ajax call, suddenly get 404 (Not Found)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My website is running unchanged for a few weeks now (running on Azure cloud),
suddenly, when calling a function on the server side from the view, i'm getting 404 (Not Found).
tried from 3 different PCs,
it looks like call is correct, i can't find what might be the issue.

View calling the function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Submit() {
        $("#divLoader").show();
        var pdata = new FormData();
        var files = $("#CSVFile").get(0).files;
        pdata.append('CSVFile', files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "OrderWarehouse/Submit",
            type: "POST",
            data: pdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                // var input = $("#CSVFile");
                //input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
                $("#divLoader").hide();
                if (data.success == 0) {
                    swal("Error!", data.excep, "error").then((value) => { location.reload(); })

                }
                else {

                    swal("Success!", data.excep, "success").then((value) => { location.reload(); })
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#divLoader").hide();
                swal("Error!", "Unknown error", "error").then((value) => { location.reload(); })
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here is the exception i'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Published my website to Azure again , Now it's working again